# Kernel Compile Error: gcc: error: elf_i386: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

I've got stuck in downgrade my kernel version to 2.6.22.
The error message is :

SYSCALL arch/i386/kernel/vsyscall-int80.so
  gcc: error: elf_i386: No such file or directory
  make[1]: *** [arch/i386/kernel/vsyscall-int80.so] Error 1
  make: *** [arch/i386/kernel] Error 2

I've tried to google for answers, like downgrade my gcc version, etc. But nothing happens.
My OS is ubuntu 11.04 with kernel version 3.1.4 .

So what's wrong is it? 
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: why would you want to downgrade?

Answer (score 22):

Can you check the vdso makefile which should be in arch/x86/vdso/Makefile.

find the line

```
 VDSO_LDFLAGS
```

there exists two lines one for x64 and another for x32 bit systems.

it should have

```
 -m elf_x86_64
```

and another one

```
 -m elf_x86
```

replace them like

```
 -m64
```

and

```
 -m32
```

respectively.

Reference to bug fix [Link1 Lockergnome](http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/Bug-546929-binutils-unrecognised-emulation-mode-elf_x86_64--ftopict506019.html) and [Link2 ubuntu](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/185698).

Comment: while your answer may solve other people's problems, it doesn't solve this case since in the question @KMHook indicates that problematic syscall occurs in the file `arch/i386/kernel/vsyscall-int80.so`, and yet you are suggesting to change a some lines in `arch/x86/` directory.

Answer (score 2):

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762977/559885) answer for this problem, and changed the `-m elf_i386` part to `-m32` in `Makefile` stored in `arch/i386/kernel` directory, and it solved the problem, for the future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the specified Makefile file (arch/x86/vdso/Makefile) and it fixed the problem.
My platform is Ubuntu-12.04, Linux 3.13.0-30.

Answer (score -5):

download and install the headers from http://www.howopensource.com/2012/07/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-5-quantal-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/ and u will not get the error anymore

Comment: The question seems to be actively trying to downgrade to 2.6.22 specifically, so a guide to upgrading to 3.5 doesn't seem relevant...?

Comment: Agreed with what Tony said. -1